# C++ template error from typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, stl

The error comes from `type& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )` which locates outside of AssocArray.
I'm confused why I get the error message:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

**Edit:**

I have tried these following statements:

```
typedef typename std::pair<key, value> type;

typedef std::pair<key, value> type; 

using type = std::pair<key, value>;
```

they didn't work either.

```
template <typename key, typename value>
class AssocArray
{
public:
    typedef typename std::pair<typename key, typename value> type;

    bool addItem(key& k, value& v);

    bool isItem(key& k);

    type& operator[] (key& k);
protected:
private:
    std::vector<type> vecData;
};

template <typename key, typename value>
type& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(vecData.begin(), vecData.end(),
        [&](type& param)
    {
        return param.first == key;
    }
    );
    if(vecData.end() != iter)
        return *iter;

    value v;
    vecData.push_back(std::make_pair(k, v));
    return *vecData.rbegin();
}

template <typename key, typename value>
bool AssocArray<key, value>::isItem( key& k )
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(vecData.begin(), vecData.end(),
        [&](type& param)
    {
        return param.first == key;
    }
    );

    return vecData.end() != iter;
}

template <typename key, typename value>
bool AssocArray<key, value>::addItem( key& k, value& v )
{
    if(isItem(k)) return false;

    vecData.push_back(std::make_pair(k, v));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have some redundant `typename`s there.

Comment: Not sure why that `typedef` wouldn't work. Have you tried `using type = std::pair<key, value>;`?

Comment: You shouldn't re-specify template parameters inside the class.

Comment: @Rapptz it doesn't work either.

Comment: @chris, why not? STL use that technique everythere.

Comment: `template <typename key, typename value>
type& ...` ― `type` is unknown at this point. You need to use a fully qualified name.

Comment: @user2609040, Did you mean `typedef std::pair<key, value> type;`?

Comment: `template <typename key, typename value> typedef std::pair<key, value> type;`  and  `template <typename key, typename value> type& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )` maybe.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, A templated typedef isn't possible without a using alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As n.m. pointed out, you need something like this:

```
template <typename key, typename value>
AssocArray<key,value>::type& AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k )
{
    ...
```

or with C++11:

```
template <typename key, typename value>
auto AssocArray<key, value>::operator[]( key& k ) -> type &
{
    ...
```

Since `type` is a member of the class, the name doesn't become known until you are within the context of the class, either by qualifying it or waiting until after specifying that you are defining a member of the class.

Comment: I forgot the trailing return type could do that. There's also a C++1y option, which is to just return `auto &`.

Comment: ... or `decltype(auto)`, if you REALLY want to confuse people.

Comment: Just to extend @Vaughn Cato's answer: Similar errors also occur when not using full namespace in `typedef typename ...`. Apparently GCC lets this go but VC++ doesn't.